# Orchard Collaboration in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I'm creating an application using orchard. While developing, I heard about "Orchard Collaboration". I was unable to know what exactly it is. I had studied its documentation from [THIS LINK](https://reviews.financesonline.com/p/orchard-collaboration/)   Can anybody let me know about it?

Comment: Both answers are literally copy pasted from the link you yourself provided, which is not the documentation. You'll probably find all the answers you're looking for on the [official site](http://orchardcollaboration.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orchard Collaboration is a free, open source ticketing system, project management and collaboration framework build on top of the Orchard CMS. This link should provide all information you want to know about Orchard Collaboration.

By ticketing system, yes, it means something like Jira (not Jeera :) ) or other help desk systems.

Can you explain more, what do you mean by non-orchard applications?

Comment: here non-orchard means as like applications which were not built on orchard cms.

Comment: Well, Orchardcollaboration is a combination of Orchard modules & themes & Orchard receipts. that will be hosted by Orchard CMS. You can only host Orchard modules and orchard themes by Orchard host. If by "including", you mean communicating with the other software and services, it can be done using custom Orchard modules.

Answer (score 0):

Orchard Collaboration is a free, open source ticketing system, project management and collaboration framework build on top of the Orchard CMS. This [link](http://orchardcollaboration.com/) should provide all information you want to know about Orchard Collaboration.

Comment: How should we include our orchard project in collaboration(ticketing system) ? can we include non-orchard applications ?

Comment: @srikanthreddy As its stated in official docs, "Orchard Collaboration is a free, open source ticketing system, project management and collaboration framework build on top of the Orchard CMS".Since its build on Orchard CMS, i m not sure what you mean by including non-orchard applications?

Comment: Can I know what exactly what ticketing system is ? Is it like jeera ?

Comment: @srikanthreddy Yes more or less like the same. Read the docs to get more info on the same. Accept the post if it was helpful. Cheers.